# JavaScript regex, searching for hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I search some text for any and all hashtags (alphanumeric AND underscore AND hyphen) and wrap them in span tags
eg search

```
some_string = "this is some text with 3 hashtags #Tag1 and #tag-2 and #tag_3 in it"
```

and convert it to:

```
"this is some text with 3 hashtags <span>#Tag1</span> and <span>#tag-2</span> and <span>#tag_3</span> in it"
```

I've got this so far:

```
    some_string = some_string.replace(/\(#([a-z0-9\-\_]*)/i,"<span>$1</span>");
```

but one fault is it doesn't include the # in the  wrappings like it should.
It seems to output:

```
"this is some text with 3 hashtags <span>Tag1</span> and #tag-2 and #tag_3 in it "
```

Also it only detects the first hashtag that it comes across (eg. `#Tag1` in this sample), it should detect all.

Also I need the hashtags to be a minimum of 1 character AFTER the #. So # on its own should not match.

Thanks

Comment: I think you may have fat-fingered: `some_string = some_string.replace(/(#[a-z0-9-_]*)/i,"$1");`. If not, that's your bug (there's an extra open parenthesis in your original post).

Comment: Also, in the future you should try testing your code on a Javascript/Regex playground like [this one](http://burkeware.com/software/regex_playground.html)

Comment: Just a suggestion; maybe it would make sense to look for a whitespace character before the hash mark? So if someone writes "Here's a link to my site: www.example.com/viewinfo#bio", it won't do anything to the hash in there.

Comment: Great suggestion Katana!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this replace call:

**EDIT:** if you want to skip `http://site.com/#tag` kind of strings then use:

```
var repl = some_string.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, '$1<span>$2</span>');
```

Comment: The regular expression is different, and would match things the original poster did not want to match.

Comment: Getting closer, however that also will match #tag*1 etc. They need to only include alphanumeric characters AND _ AND - AND start with # obviously....and at least 2 characters (including #) and

Comment: ^\s can also be written \S

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, that works well. Katana in the comments in the other answer had a good suggestion to make sure there was a space before the # so as to not match url/#anchor etc situations. I would suggest space or any NON alphanumeric character or - or _ could be acceptable starting anchor. So hello.#tag would match. wow, getting more complicated the more i think about it :(

Comment: @MartinS: Yes I already provided an option as per your discussion with him, see the answer below EDIT heading.

Comment: Also - and _ can not be directly following the #.

Comment: Couple of issues with it, if there is a proceeding space, the space gets removed. Also needs to accept any non alphanumeric character directly proceeding the hash, not only space. eg "this is a tag.#tag" will match #tag or comma, or any other non alphanumeric or -_ character etc, etc..

Comment: Ok fixed bots issues, pls check.

Comment: if there is emoji or other language or connect hash string then this regex not work.   `var str = '#a#friend❤️  dleokfir #日文 cksieje';`   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562316/get-string-after-specific-character-regex-match-all-emoji-and-different-languag

Comment: You're trying to match unicode characters and that are not supported in JS regex.

Answer (score 5):

This is the regular expression you want:

```
/(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)/ig
```

The `i` makes it case insensitive, which you already had.  But the `g` makes it look through the whole string ("g" stands for "global").  Without the `g`, the matching stops at the first match.

This also includes a fix to remove the incorrect parenthesis and some unneeded backslashes.

Comment: Thanks John, I changed it a bit to include the # tag as that should also be wrapped in the span tags. Changed to: /(#[a-z0-9-_]*)/ig 
however I need to make sure there are a minimum of 2 characters in the match. The above will match # on its own. Needs to be # plus 1 more alpanumeric character as the 2nd character (and - and _ can come 3rd character +)

Comment: @MartinS then you should update your post as it becomes a different question. /(#[a-z][a-z0-9-_]*)/ig

Comment: Hyphen if doesn't appear at 1st or at last position in character class, needs to be escaped. Otherwise it will make it a range.

Comment: Updated based on the comments.

Comment: Thanks John, that seems to be working almost perfectly! I need it to detect for any alphanumeric ( or - or _ ) directly proceeding the # symbol, and not match in those cases. SO space,comma,dot,exclamation,# etc directly proceeding the # is ok. just not a-z0-9-_ etc

Comment: @MartinS: Follow this link, and you can figure out the new conditions on your own! http://burkeware.com/software/regex_playground.html You'll want to figure out what characters are allowed prior to the hash tag, then put those in before the opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Solution which works in multiline and non-latin symbols:

```
var getHashTags = function(string) {
   var hashTags, i, len, word, words;
   words = string.split(/[\s\r\n]+/);
   hashTags = [];
   for (i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
     word = words[i];
     if (word.indexOf('#') === 0) {
       hashTags.push(word);
     }
   }
   return hashTags;
};
```

or in CoffeeScript:

```
getHashTags = (string) ->
  words = string.split /[\s\r\n]+/
  hashTags = []
  hashTags.push word for word in words when word.indexOf('#') is 0
  hashTags
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match `http://site/#hashs`, use this one instead*:

```
string.replace(/(^|\s)#[a-zA-Z0-9][\w-]*\b/g, "$1<span>$2</span>");
```

It will match:

- `#word`
- `#word_1` and `#word-1`
- `#word` in `#word?` or `#word"` or `#word.` or `#word,`

It won't match

- `"#word` nor `,#word` nor `.#word`
- `/#word`
- `#_word` nor `#-word`
- `wor#d`

The things you want and don't want to match may vary in different cases.

Try it yourself at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kCkh4V/3).

---

* The current accepted answer, posted by @anubhava, claims to skip url hash's but fails doing it.