# Get hashtags from string with trim spaces and new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

[image: textarea text and result console log]

## The javascript code:

How can I find hashtags without newline or spaces or tabs just hashtags without url hashtags?

```
function findHashtags(searchText) {
    var regexp = /\#\w\w+\s?/g
    result = searchText.match(regexp);
    if (result) {
        result.map(function(s) { return s.trim() });
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"labas #kaip sekas #hey".match(/#\w\w+\s?/g).map((x) => x.trim()).filter((x) => x !== "")` enjoy

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `\b` instead of `\s?` - a word boundary instead of additional whitespace to not capture whitespace.  Use `\B` (not a word boundary) to separate your url hashtags from urls that end in word characters.

So:

```
function findHashtags(searchText) {
    var regexp = /\B\#\w\w+\b/g
    result = searchText.match(regexp);
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which invoked thusly:

```
findHashtags("http://www.masrawy.com/Sports/Sports_News/details/2014/9/5/338281#HPOFEATURE\n#ss\nddd\n#ddd jaaja ksks #sfsfsf\n#ggdg#hdhhd")
```

Then returns:

```
["#ss", "#ddd", "#sfsfsf", "#ggdg", "#hdhhd"]
```

Note that this will fail if the url ends in anything but a word character (`a-z0-9_`).  The only option besides that would be to capture and more effectively trim whitespace:

```
function findHashtags(searchText) {
    var regexp = /(\s|^)\#\w\w+\b/gm
    result = searchText.match(regexp);
    if (result) {
        result = result.map(function(s){ return s.trim();});
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working good bro, so how can i remove url hashtags ??

Comment: in the 1st line is url i dont need the hashtag of url on the result
`["#ss", "#ddd", "#sfsfsf", "#ggdg", "#hdhhd"] `
i need it without `#HPOFEATURE`

Comment: @AhmedMiro  Sorry, I missed that requirement.

Comment: Sorry Man can you fix this please :
## The hashtags maybe contain any language unicode Arabic, Japanese .. etc ##
## This Code can help ##
`var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\p{L}+$");

  unicodeWord.test("Русский"); // true
  unicodeWord.test("日本語"); // true
  unicodeWord.test("العربية"); // true
`

Comment: @AhmedMiro see my answer on similar question, my solution supports any language as well as multiline strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864482/javascript-regex-searching-for-hashtags/32049446#32049446

Answer (score 11):

If you care about readability simply do:

```
yourText.split(' ').filter(v=> v.startsWith('#'))
```

Comment: Not only more readable, it's considerably faster than regex way in other answers. I clocked times for both on a large string with around 20 hash tags. For the same results, avg regex time: 0.250ms, avg time for this solution: 0.100ms.

Definitely a better solution!

Comment: what about this? `yourText.split(/\s/gm).filter((s) => s.startsWith('#'))`

Answer (score 2):

Put the space match in a look-ahead, maybe with `$` too

```
"#foo #bar #baz".match(/#[\w]+(?=\s|$)/g); // ["#foo", "#bar", "#baz"]
```

Now you can more easily modify the rest (i.e. add things next to `\w`) to match any valid hashtag

Answer (score 2):

Get hast tag from string

```
function getHashTag = function (tagString)
    {
      var tagListArray = [];
      var regexp = new RegExp('#([^\\s]*)', 'g');
      var tmplist = tagString.match(regexp);
      for (var w in tmplist) {
          var hashSub = tmplist[ w ].split('#');
          for (var x in hashSub) {
              if (hashSub[x] != "")
              {
                  if (hashSub[x].substr(hashSub[x].length - 1) == ":")
                  {
                      hashSub[x] = hashSub[x].slice(0, -1);
                  }
                  if (hashSub[x] != "") {
                      tagListArray.push(hashSub[x]);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return tagListArray;
    }

    console.log(getHashTag("#test#logic:main dummytext hello #stack:overflow"))
```

Comment: Thanks you have saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showTags(){
          var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
          var result = text.split(' ').filter(v=> v.startsWith('#'));
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter text or paragraph</h1>

    <textarea type="text" id="text"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="showTags()">Get Hashtags</button><br><br>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showTags(findTages) {
var text = findTages;
var tags = [];
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == "#") {
        for (let l = i; l < text.length; l++) {
            if (text[l] == " ") {
                tags.push((text.substring(i, l)));
                break;
            };
        };
    };
};
return tags;
```

};

let a = `I Love #Coding EveryTime Give Me Credit On Your Website My Name Is #Avi Boy`;
console.log(showTags((a)));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).