# Regex find all string ( include emoji, any language) after specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex find all string after specific character.

`var str = '#a#friend❤️ dleokfir #日文 cksieje';`
->
`['a', 'friend❤️', '日文']`
  
`var str = '';`
->
`[]`

```
function getArr(str) {
  var re = /#([a-z0-9_\\pL_]+)/gi;
  var arr = [];
  // ..  get string after #
  str.replace(re, function( a,b ) {
    arr.push( b );
  });

  return arr;
}

getArr(str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/tJ3jM8/1

Comment: `string.split('#').pop()` gets you everything after the hash

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried but return `日文 cksieje` not correct result I want   https://jsfiddle.net/udugpnyb/

Comment: That's confusing, are you just trying to do this -> https://jsfiddle.net/udugpnyb/1/

Comment: Javascript regex doesn't support unicode characters. You cannot use `\pL` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negated regex:

```
/#([^#\s]*)/g
```

which means match 0 or more of non-space or non-hash character after `#` in input.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udugpnyb/13/)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ3jM8/2)

**Code:**

```
var str = `#a#friend❤️ dleokfir #日文 cksieje`;

var re = /#([^#\s]*)/g; 
var m;
var matches=[];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["a", "friend❤️", "日文"]
```