# search command ignores special characters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, special-characters

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to parse Google Calendar events and create a Google Document if the following string is found in the title or description of the event "#notes".

**What actually happens:** A document is created as soon as the string "notes" is found. It doesn't require an hashtag. The same thing happens with @.

```
function createMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod() { 

  //<-------------------------------------VARIABLES

  // get today's date
  var today = new Date();

  // number of hours from now to check for meetings
  var hours = 2

  // create variable for now
  var now = new Date();

  // create variable for number of hours from now in milliseconds
  var period_from_now = new Date(now.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  // retrieve all calendar events for time period with @notes string
  var tagword = ('#notes');
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, period_from_now, {search: tagword}) ;
  Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);

}  // functionCreateMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod
```

The log commands tells me that it found one event but the event in question just has 'notes' in it's title, no hashtag. Thanks for all help.

**EDIT**
I think I found the problem but I'm still stumped about solving it. It seems that the search option from .getEvents ignores most special characters and returns a positive whenever you search for a special character. For example, I replaced my original search for tagword with this:

```
var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, period_from_now, {search: 'notes' + '@' +'#' + '±' }) ;
```

It gives me a positive match on my search while I don't have either a '@', a '#' nor a '±' in my event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does seem odd that it ignores special characters however here is a work around that should work:

```
  var tagword = '#notes';
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, period_from_now, {search : tagword})
  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i in events) {
      if ( events[i].getTitle().indexOf(tagword) >-1 || events[i].getDescription().indexOf(tagword) >-1) {
        //do something
      }
      }
  }
```

Basically it will find all events that have notes (ignoring the special characters) then loop through the event titles and descriptions to check if the tag word is present (including special characters).

Comment: That completely solved the issue. In hindsight it's so obvious I should've thought of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some Regex to do what you are trying to do in Javascript.

I am not exactly sure how to do it for your particular case but here are two references that can help you out.

[JS Extract HashTags From Text](http://geekcoder.org/js-extract-hashtags-from-text/)

[JS Regex Searching for HashTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864482/javascript-regex-searching-for-hashtags)

I hope this helps !

**EDIT**

try

```
var tagword = ('/#/g' + notes);
OR
var tagword = ('/#notes/g');
```

I tried it out and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Plz_dont_hate I extended my answer

Comment: I added quotes to the first expression so it would compile. But both expression detect neither 'notes' nor '#notes'. I also tried to create a regex but I don't think you can send a Regex into the search command, otherwise I get an error. Thank you for your help so far.