# Hashtag Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to create a similar thing to the character counter on this website - https://character-counter.uk/. However, instead of counting every character I only want to count hashtags. So if I entered #happy and #sad the counter would return the number 2.

I'm new to javaScript and jQuery so am not sure how I could get this to happen.

Say I have this html

```
  <textarea rows="16" class="form-control"></textarea>

  <div class="remaining-counter">Characters Counted:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
  class="well text-well">0</span></div>
```

I want the 0 belonging to the text-well span to jump up once whenever a hashtag is typed into the text area.

I've been tinkering around with some things but so far can only come up with this code

```
var count = 0;

 $("textarea").on("input", function() {

  if ($(this).val().match(/#/)) {
    $('.text-well').html(count++);
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

When entering it into the character counter site using the console the counter still counts up whenever I start typing into the textarea and then resets and starts counting up in twos when a # is entered.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: Instead of incrementing every time the user types, I'd suggest doing the entire count on each input event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can simply use the `match()` method to find the number of hashtags within the value of the given `textarea`, something like this:

```js
$("textarea").on("input", function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  var count = (text.match(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/g) || []).length;
  $('.text-well').html(count);
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" class="form-control">Lorem #ipsum dolor #sit amet #consectetur adipiscing</textarea>

<div class="remaining-counter">Hashtags Counted:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="well text-well">0</span></div>
```

Note that I got the hashtag regex from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864482/javascript-regex-searching-for-hashtags)

Comment: test##test count as 1

Comment: @GiorgioCatenacci so it should - it's a count of hashtags, not hash

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I've just been asked to see whether any duplicate hashtags can not be counted and maybe underlined in red or something. I've had a look at various other questions but nothing seems to be working. Any help?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question for that as it's a very big logic change to your original request

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$("textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {
if ($(this).val().match(/#/)) {
$('.text-well').html(count++);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count hash tags, requiring each pound sign counted to be followed by at least one word character:

```js
$("textarea").on("keyup", function() {
    var matches = $(this).val().match(/#\w+\b/g);
    var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    $('.text-well').html(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>

<div class="remaining-counter">Characters Counted:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
class="well text-well">0</span></div>
```

Basically:

- Instead of trying to keep track of a counter, do the entire count every time.
- Use `.match(pattern).length` to get the number of matches, remembering to use the `g` flag so you actually count all matches.
- If you only want to count hashes, `/#/` works fine. If you want to match hash *tags*, ensure the hashtag is followed by a letter by using `/#\w/`.
- Use the `keyup` event to ensure your count is updated on every letter press.