# Search a string for hashtags (with spaces) and wrap with spans

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to search a string and wrap hashtags with spans.

I found a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864482/javascript-regex-searching-for-hashtags).

`var repl = some_string.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, '$1<span>$2</span>');`

But I'd like to update it to fit my needs. I have some tags that have spaces in them that won't work with the regex there. I know that it's not technically a hashtag if they have spaces but that's the data I have to work with.

For example:

`text text text text #tag1 #tag2 tag2secondWord #tag3 / withSlash #tag4 #tag5`

will give:

`text text text text <span>#tag1</span> <span>#tag2</span> tag2secondWord <span>#tag3</span> / withSlash <span>#tag4</span> <span>#tag5</span>`

and I would want:

`text text text text <span>#tag1</span> <span>#tag2 tag2secondWord</span> <span>#tag3 / withSlash</span> <span>#tag4</span> <span>#tag5</span>`

I've tried to come up with the answer on my own but I'm not very comfortable with regex.

Comment: So is it that as soon as there’s one `#`, everything after it is considered part of some hashtag?

Comment: yep thats correct, until it reaches the next `#` @Ry-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(^|\W)(#.*?(?= #|$))
```

Once it finds a hash (`#`) it saves all characters until it encounters either a space followed by a hash, or the end-of-string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OvhcDZ/1/)

```js
var str = 'text text text text #tag1 #tag2 tag2secondWord #tag3 / withSlash #tag4 #tag5';
console.log(str.replace(/(^|\W)(#.*?(?= #|$))/ig, '$1<span>$2</span>'));
```